# DbDataAdapter vs DataAdapter

Tags: c#, ado.net, dataadapter

I keep hearing `DbDataAdapter` this days. It is an `abstract class` of adapter.

But When should i prefer `DbDataAdapter` over `DataAdapter`, and what is the difference between `DbDataAdapter` and `DataAdapter`(on performance and functionality)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, `DbDataAdapter` is an abstract class, that inherits from `DataAdapter`. As said in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.common.dbdataadapter.aspx):

> Inheritors of DbDataAdapter implement a set of functions to provide
>   strong typing, but inherit most of the functionality needed to fully
>   implement a DataAdapter.

And for perfomance, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.aspx):

> If you are connecting to a SQL Server database, you can increase
>   overall performance by using the SqlDataAdapter along with its
>   associated SqlCommand and SqlConnection objects.For OLE DB-supported
>   data sources, use the DataAdapter with its associated OleDbCommand and
>   OleDbConnection objects.For ODBC-supported data sources, use the
>   DataAdapter with its associated OdbcCommand and OdbcConnection
>   objects.For Oracle databases, use the DataAdapter with its associated
>   OracleCommand and OracleConnection objects.